# Can't display the first word with hasNext()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to split words with **hasNext**() and a **loop**, but it doesn't work, here is my code and below is the output

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter your full name");
String name = kb.next();

while(kb.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(kb.next());
}
```

Here is the output it displays:

> ```
> Please enter your full name
> John Smith
> ```

But it is supposed to display:

> ```
> John
> Smith
> ```

Why? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You do:

```
String name = kb.next();
```

But you never print `name`.

If you just want get the user input word by word and print in separate lines you can do:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your full name");

while (kb.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(kb.next());
}
```

Example:

```
John Paul Smith
```

Output

```
John
Paul
Smith
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial call to `kb.next` pops "John" from the queue. Then, you enter a loop and print the *next* return statement from `kb.next`, which is "Smith". Try the following,

```java
System.out.println("Please enter your full name");
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

while (kb.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(kb.next());
}
```

Comment: @Anderson Vieira beat me to it.

Comment: I had the variable name because I was splitting the words initialized into the variable. Then, I decided to get the word by user input (I'm just practicing different ways...) but as you guys can tell, I am totally a beginner to Java, so I didn't know I had to delete it. Thanks to both of you! Your solution worked!